# Kendo DropDownList not populating json string list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two KendoDropDownList boxes, the first is loading just fine. The second cascades from the first and should be loading a simple array/list of strings return as json. I can see that the GetDistinctImportDates is returning a populated JsonResult as I would expect.

What am I missing?

```
        public JsonResult GetDistinctImportDates(string clientid)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> importDates = null;

        var dates = client.GetStringAsync(string.Format("api/ImportHeader/distinctdates/{0}", clientid)).Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dates))
        {
            importDates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(dates);
        }

        return Json(importDates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    <div id="clientsArea">
    @(
        Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("clients")
            .OptionLabel("Select Client...")
            .DataValueField("ClientId")
            .DataTextField("ClientName")
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetClients", "Home");
                });
            })
    )
</div>
<div id="datesArea">
    @(
        Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("importDates")
            .CascadeFrom("clients")
            .OptionLabel("Select Import Date...")
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetDistinctImportDates", "Home")
                        .Data("filterImportDates");
                });  
            })
            .AutoBind(false)
            .Enable(false)
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `ServerFiltering` on your child dropdown's datasource to make it work:

```
Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("importDates")
            .CascadeFrom("clients")
            .OptionLabel("Select Import Date...")
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetDistinctImportDates", "Home")
                        .Data("filterImportDates");
                }).ServerFiltering(true);
            })
            .AutoBind(false)
            .Enable(false)
```

From the [cascading FAQ:](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/combobox/cascading):

> Q: `The serverFiltering` is disabled and the child combobox does not
>   work?
>
> A: When the `serverFiltering` is disabled, then the combobox will
>   not make any additional requests to the server. Hence it will filter
>   the initial data using the parent's dataValueField property. If no
>   items are found, then the child combobox will be empty. If you need to
>   use child combobox with disabled server filtering, then you will need
>   to provide all neccessary data on the client.

Comment: That was the issue, thank you so much. I just never found that anywhere.